# Closing out ssh session in MobaXterm and WinSCP after being idle for a few minutes

Tags: ssh

Well the problem I have is that when I log in via ssh in MobaXterm everything is fine when I am inside the terminal but if I leave it for a moment without doing anything for a few minutes it closes

Session stopped - Press to exit tab - Press R to restart session - Press S to save terminal output to file Network error: Software caused connection abort

And on the other hand, in WinScp it also closes because it is inactive and I get the error Host is nor communicating for more that 15 secondand I have to reconnect This is very annoying if I am having other jobs in parallel, the curious thing about this is that this does not happen when I am in my office and only when I am at home, I don't know if it is my internet network/modem or my computer's firewall, It is normal? I would appreciate your contributions please.

```
información de mi servidor:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```